# Alter sql Table data format

Tags: sql, date

I have a `Nvarchar` column in a database table which contains date values. Date values are stored in two formats

```
2008-05-20
22/04/2011
```

Now I need to convert this column to a `date` column. When I'm try the following query:

```
 set dateformat dmy
  alter table  tblDocumentRevision
  alter column RevisionDate date
```

it returns an error:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Please help me to solve this

Comment: you will probably need to wrote more code than that; or even an SSIS task....

Comment: `2008-05-20` isn't really in syntax like `dmy`

Comment: No,According to my knowledge ,you have to add a new column with datatype DATE and make a query to copy all data from your existing column to new column in single date format, and Then delete old column and rename new column name to old name

Comment: You need to have all the dates in the same format for a simple alter to work

Answer (score 2):

Update the date string in the table so they all have the same format (one that SQL server can cast from) before you change the type to DateTime.